# How to use hash into hashes in R

Tags: r, hash, hashtable

How can I use hash in R in order to the key values has other hash?

In python I would have something like this:

`hash = {}
hash["other_hash"] = {}
hash["other_hash"]["value"] = 5`

In R I'm trying to use hash library and env structure to create hashs but I can't create one hash inside the key value of other hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list()`:

```
hash <- list(other_hash = list(value = 5))
hash$other_hash$value #5
```

Comment: Or if python syntax feels familiar, `hash[["other_hash"]][["value"]]` will yield the same